# Modal UIViewController will not push to next UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

**The start of the structure is as follows...**

UITabBarController -> UINavigationController(s)

**From each of the UINavigationControllers, I have a UIBarButtonItem that modally presents a UIViewController.**

**This UIViewController has a MKMapView with pins at multiple locations. When clicked, they display an annotation with a disclosure button.**

Within this UIViewController, it is my intention to push a detail page (UITableViewController) when pressing the disclosure button of the annotation. The method calloutAccessoryControlTapped: receives the appropriate pin, but the transition to the next controller fails.

**I have tried every combination of the following methods...**

1. [self.navigationController ...]
2. [self.parentViewController ...]
3. [self.parentViewController.navigationController ...]

**with the method being either...**

1. presentModalViewController:
2. pushViewController:

**I have done all of these with the UIViewController being on its own, and also with it embedded inside of a UINavigationController.**

**All of these properties return null...**

1. self.navigationController
2. self.parentViewController
3. self.parentViewController.navigationController

**This is the first time I've used storyboard for an Xcode project. Am I missing a step?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting rid of the code and implementing the transitions in storyboard by control dragging from the button to the view controller you wish to load modally. When the "Storyboard Segue" menu pops up select "modal". In the modal view controller, I like to use code to return from the modal by calling:

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To Presenting Storyboard View Controllers Programmatically scroll to that section in [gravityjack](http://gravityjack.com/ios-5-for-developers-what-you-need-to-know) on the link provided.

For example, I have a  view controller that I created in storyboard which I can call programmatically with the following two statements:

```
    SettingsViewController *settingsVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settingsVC"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:settingsVC animated:YES];
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm trying to do this programmatically. I'd have to make a segue attachment to a LOT of views from to the UIViewController, which would be a really big mess if something needed to change in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I've added a link in my answer for presenting view controllers programmatically.

Comment: this is a helpful read, but not the troubleshooting type of answer i'm looking for. i've pushed, popped, and presented many controllers within my code; the question is on this specific instance not triggering properly. i'd like to accept this answer, since you're answer will probably guide others asking this question to the right place for them, though, if an answer comes along that is in a better direction for me, i'll have to award to someone else. thanks again!

Comment: i've edited my question to make my intentions for the *push* clearer. i'm not so good at communicating! sorry if i wasn't asking correctly. thanks!

Comment: Solved the problem by storing a reference to the navigationController of the desired UIViewController in a singleton. Then created a method inside the singleton that dismissed the modal view controller, and pushed to the desired UIViewController. What a mess! Please continue to answer if you have a more elegant solution! :)

Comment: I think there is a much more elegant solution [found here](http://www.kickasslabs.com/2009/07/03/uinavigationcontroller-tricks/), although it doesn't use any of the storyboard stuff (which makes it pretty lightweight, in my opinion).